# What would you call the building a seamstress works in?

Tags: single-word-requests

Just wondering what would the building or establishment that  seamstress/dressmaker work in be called

Comment: I can't think of a single word. Some might be employed in a *clothing factory*. For outsourced work, the building might be called a *home* or *garage* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about individual alterations, or a factory setting in which dresses are handmade en masse?

If the former, it'd be a 'tailor shop' or just 'tailor'. If it's a fancy one, 'alterations boutique' might be an appropriate term.

If the latter, 'sweatshop' is often the term used.